# Adding columns dynamically to a pandas dataframe, from a list contained in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which the first column contains a list of random size, from 0 to around 10 items in each list. This dataframe also contains several other columns of data.

I would like to insert as many columns as the length of the longest list, and then populate the values across sequentially such that each column has one item from the list in column one.

I was unsure of a good way to go about this.

```
sample = [[[0,2,3,7,8,9],2,3,4,5],[[1,2],2,3,4,5],[[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],2,3,4,5]]
headers = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
df = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns = headers)
```

In this example I would like to add 9 columns after column 1, as this is the maxiumum length of the list in the third row of the dataframe. These columns would be populated with:

```
 0 2  3    7    8     9  NULL NULL NULL in the first row,
 1 2 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL in the second, etc...
```

Comment: could you show an example?

Comment: Please build some code with a *copyable* sample dataframe, and showing what you would like to get, and what is your current attemp. It will greatly help others to give relevant answers. BTW as a new user, you should read [ask] to know how to present question on this site...

Comment: Did you try my answer? The solution applies in the same way with your example set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit to fit OPs edit

This is how I would do it. First I would pad the lists of the original column so that they're all the same length and it's easier to work with them. Afterwards it's a matter of creating the columns and filling it with the value corresponding to the position in the list. Let's say our lists are of size up to 4 for an easier example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns = headers)
df = df.rename(columns={'col1':'col_of_lists'})
max_length = max(df['col_of_lists'].apply(lambda x:len(x)))
df['col_of_lists'] = df['col_of_lists'].apply(lambda x:x + ([np.nan] * (max_length - len(x))))
for i in range(max_length):
    df['col_'+str(i)] = df['col_of_lists'].apply(lambda x: x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to turn a series of lists into separate columns is to use `apply` to convert them into a Series, which triggers the `'expand'` result type:

```
result = df['col1'].apply(pd.Series)
```

At this point, we can adjust the columns from the automatically numbered to include the name of the original `'col1'`, for example:

```
result.columns = [
    'col1_{}'.format(i + 1)
    for i in result.columns]
```

Finally, we can join it back to the original DataFrame. Using the fact that this was the first column makes it easy, just joining it to the left of the original frame, dropping the original `'col1'` in the process:

```
result = result.join(df.drop('col1', axis=1))
```

You can even do it all as a one-liner, by using the `rename()` method to change column names:

```
df['col1'].apply(pd.Series).rename(
    lambda i: 'col1_{}'.format(i + 1),
    axis=1,
).join(df.drop('col1', axis=1))
```